# Sample size calculation for multiple testing setting with fdrsampsize package

Tags: multiple-comparisons, statistical-power, false-discovery-rate

I would like to calculate a suitable sample size for experiments where multiple testing is an issue and the FDR is used as a measure of significance. I have found a paper (http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/21/23/4263.full) about calculating sample sizes in this situation, and an accompanying R package (manual http://www.stjuderesearch.org/depts/biostats/software/fdrsampsize/fdrsampsize-manual.pdf).

Below is some example code demonstrating an attempted sample size calculation for a correlation analysis:

```
# this is for ease of demonstration - I actually used 164 correlation coefficients from a previous experiment
> effect.sizes <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8)

> sample.size <- fdr.sampsize (fdr=0.05, ave.pow=0.8, eff.size=effect.sizes, pow.func=power.tcorr)$n
```

However, the paper is beyond my statistical understanding and I'm not confident that I am putting in the right numbers.

What I am struggling with is that in a sample size calculation for a single hypothesis, you put in a threshold effect size. For example, for a correlation analysis, you might say 'What sample size do I need to say that I've got a significant correlation with a (threshold) coefficient of 0.8 (with power=0.8 and alpha=0.05)?'

However, with the fdr.sampsize function from the fdrsampsize package there seems to be nowhere to specify a threshold effect size. In the code above, is `sample.size` the sample size required to say that any of these correlation coefficients that are not zero (i.e. all of them) is significant? If so, this is not what I want - I am happy to just say that the top correlation coefficients (e.g. those above 0.8) are significant.

If this is the case, could I get a suitable sample size by reducing the power parameter to be equal to the fraction of correlation coefficients in the list that are above 0.8? So for the example above, could I use `ave.pow=0.2`? Or alternatively should I set any coefficients that I don't want to call significant to zero, i.e. `effect.sizes <- c(0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.9)`? The demo data for the package seems to use coefficients with a value of zero to represent cases where the null hypothesis is true, but I don't know if this is just for ease of demonstration.

The demo data also uses a power of 50%, and I don't know where that has come from, as 80% is standard for stats tests.

Also, in the paper it talks about calculating the effect.sizes parameter from background data, but it sounds very complicated, so maybe I have taken too simple an approach in just using the correlation coefficients from example data.

So basically my question is: what are the appropriate numbers to use for the `ave.pow` and `eff.size` parameters?